# Can I make phone call and receive SMS with Nexus 9?

Tags: hardware

Does the [Nexus 9](http://www.google.com/nexus/9/) come with standard phone and sms functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specs on the official website](https://www.google.com/nexus/9/) include cell radios, but the battery life estimates therein only include tabletty things (browsing and video) and not talk time. Since phones always include a talk time estimate in their battery specs, it seems like this feature isn't present.

Comment: According to [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_nexus_9-5823.php), it says: "Network Technology: GSM / HSPA / LTE" as well as "Messaging: SMS(threaded view), MMS, Email, Push Mail, IM" and "Talk time: Up to 9 h 30 min".

Answer (score 0):

No, but you may get Pushbullet. All you do is download Pushbullet on your phone, and then set it up on your tablet. This will allow you to text when your phone is on from your Nexus 9, but will not allow calling.